# Extension and argv.json showing on Chrome after lunching a code with live server in VS code

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, liveserver

I've got a few line of code I am working on and any time time I try to open it with a live server, I encounter a problem as shown in the image. I have tried to solve the issue with by looking it up on Google but could not. Why is this happening?

[image]

Comment: You don't appear to be running your Live Server in the project directory containing your HTML files

Comment: See https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer#shortcuts-to-startstop-server for launch instructions

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the live server launched with `~/.vscode/` as the root. Maybe you set `liveServer.settings.root` to `~/.vscode/` or similar? Other than that, I can't think of why this might happen.

I was wondering if that's what happens if you launch a server without opening a workspace folder, but that's not the case. When you do that, you get a message to "*Open a folder or workspace... (File -> Open Folder)*".